# KSOAP ILLEGAL PROPERTY

Tags: java, android, web-service, eclipse, ksoap2

Fiz o webservice utilizando Android e KSOAP, agora preciso consumir o webservice...
O método especificado precisa recuperar do banco todos os usuarios (idusuario,nomeusuario)

Pessoal, estou com o seguinte erro e não sei resolver :( !

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Método  é:

```
public ArrayList<Usuario> buscarTodosUsuarios() {

    ArrayList<Usuario> lista = new ArrayList<Usuario>();

    SoapObject buscarUsuario = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,BUSCARTODOS);


    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope= new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(buscarUsuario);

    envelope.implicitTypes = true;

    HttpTransportSE http = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        http.call("urn= "  + BUSCARTODOS, envelope);

        Vector<SoapObject> resposta = (Vector<SoapObject>) envelope.getResponse();

        for (SoapObject soapObject : resposta) {

            Usuario usr = new Usuario();

            usr.setIdUsuario(Integer.parseInt(soapObject.getProperty("idusuario").toString()));
            usr.setNomeUsuario(soapObject.getProperty("nomeusuario").toString());

            lista.add(usr);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
        return lista;

}
```

A classe `Usuario` é:

```
public class Usuario {
    private int idusuario;
    private String nomeusuario;


    public Usuario(){

    }

    public Usuario(int idusuario, String nomeusuario) {
        super();
        this.idusuario = idusuario;
        this.nomeusuario = nomeusuario;
    }

    public int getIdUsuario() {
        return idusuario;
    }

    public void setIdUsuario(int idusuario) {
        this.idusuario = idusuario;
    }

    public String getNomeUsuario() {
        return nomeusuario;
    }

    public void setNomeUsuario(String nomeusuario) {
        this.nomeusuario = nomeusuario;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Usuario [idusuario=" + idusuario + ", nomeusuario="
                + nomeusuario + "]";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para quem interessar....

O meu erro era que no meu webservice estava escrito "idUsuario" e "nomeUsuario" e na hora de implementar o cliente para consumir eu estava colocando:

usr.setIdUsuario(Integer.parseInt(soapObject.getProperty("**idusuario**").toString()));
usr.setNomeUsuario(soapObject.getProperty("**nomeusuario**").toString());

Basicamente o erro era esse "u" minusculo!